# Can't add a form before the add-to-cart button in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I need to create a contact form (to enquire about the product) right before the add-to-cart button on the single product page.

However WooCommerce removes my form's `form` tags from it making it impossible to use. How to prevent WooCommerce to do so?

Comment: Right before the add to cart button? You are *in* the WooCommerce add to cart form and you can't nest forms as that is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding my extra form fields inside the existing form then successfully submitting those fields using the following jQuery code:

```
$( '#my_form input[type=submit]' ).click(function() {
    var params = $( '#my_form' ).find( 'input' ).serialize(); 
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: x,
        type: 'POST',
        data: params,
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery( '#some_div' ).html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

As for when submitting the existing, normal form, then those fields are simply not taken into account by WooCommerce, so no issue here.

Answer (score 0):

some plugin maybe? Or maybe the editor strips out certain tags by default. You can use a plugin that allows you to insert html through shortcodes

You can try this plugin to insert html as shortcodes

You would create a shortcode corresponding to  form. And insert it into your post

http://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-html-snippet/